# Autosizing button child elements as button changes size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls

I have a number of buttons within a grid, that all change size based on the application being resized.  Some buttons have child elements such as an ellipse or rectangle.  I can't seem to get these to resize as well.

Here is some code:

```
<Grid DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="121">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="121*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="121*" />
            // Snip
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Name="ellipseButton" PreviewMouseDown="EllipseButtonClickedEvent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0">
            <Ellipse Width="90" Height="90" Stroke="Black"></Ellipse>
        </Button>
       // Snip
    </Grid>
```

I know that the height and width of the ellipse is explicitly set, but when I remove that, I can't seem to get the ellipse to show at all.

I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` properties of the button to `Stretch`:

```
<Button Name="ellipseButton" PreviewMouseDown="EllipseButtonClickedEvent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
   <Ellipse Stroke="Black" />
</Button>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when I copy this into my button the ellipse disappears.

Comment: Those bindings are superfluous, the important thing is the ContentAlignment on the button.

Comment: @H.B., you're right, the bindings are not necessary. I'll update my answer

Comment: @DarrenYoung, what do you mean it "disappears" ? I tried it and it works fine for me...

Comment: @Thomas that was before you edited the answer.  I'll try with your updated answer in the morning.  Thanks for the update.

Comment: Who needs sleep :)  Just checked it and it works fine now.  Thanks @Thomas.